# Magick in R is dropping data from frames when selected individually

Tags: r, imagemagick

Using this gif:

[image]

How can I get lossless frames using Magick?

```
library(magick)
a_mgif <- image_read("https://i.stack.imgur.com/kucQM.gif")

a_mgif[2]
```

I'm attempting to combine separate gifs frame-by-frame as seen here: https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/wiki/Animation-Composition but I don't know how to get past the compression.

[image]

Comment: GIF supports only 256 colors. If each image has a different set of 256 colors, then you will have trouble. Convert the images to PNG, then process them, then save as GIF. Does that help or work? You may have to provide a color map image (with -remap) with your desired 256 colors, if the automatic generation is not suitable. See the example at https://imagemagick.org/Usage/video/ regarding a common global color map and also the -remap function at https://imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#remap

Comment: I found my answer: `image_write_gif()` had loss whereas `image_write()` didn't. Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know RMagick, only the ImageMagick command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`image_write()` produces a full frame without compression.